# iptables: how to re-direct all tcp traffic to 127.0.0.1:1234?

Tags: iptables

I'm trying to come up with an iptables rule whereby I can redirect all tcp traffic incoming on eth0 to 127.0.0.1:1234. I will then listen on 127.0.0.1 with my C program and print the raw packets to console. Is this possible? Or am I going about this in completely the wrong way?

Please bear in mind that my iptables knowledge is very limited.

Here's what I've tried sofar:

sudo iptables -A INPUT -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -j DROP

but I don't want to DROP - I want to forward to 127.0.0.1:1234!

Comment: … what are you actually trying to accomplish? I guarantee you there's a better way to do things if you just tell us what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Perhaps a honeypot?

Comment: Why not using Wireshark?

Answer (score 4):

First enable routing:

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Try this:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -p tcp -i eth0  -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:1234
```

Optional to hide the real IP:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: I think MASQUERADE is not necessary, will hide real source IP

Answer (score 2):

It's a much better idea to configure iptables to send the packets to your process using netlink (search for NFLOG in the iptables manpage) or just capture raw traffic with libpcap.

This way you won't lose information and you'll keep things simple.